# Run function when if statement is true (For Loop)

Tags: php, loops, oop, for-loop

I have one issue that I can't solve. So I have for loop.

So here is little code:

```
  for ($i=0;$i<3;$i++) {
      $int = $i + 1;
      if($sms->mobio_check($servID,$request->input("code$int"))) {
          continue;
          $cart->success($product->id,$product->server->name);
      } else {
          return redirect()->to(route('mcCheckoutFailed'))->withErrors(['codeError'=>__('messages.invalidCode',['input'=>$int])]);
      }
  }
```

I want if three ifs return true to run function `$sms->success();`.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Your function return true or false ? if yes then remove continue statement .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rely on the fact that if the loop finished, then it's OK, any failures will cause the `return` in the loop to exit...

```
for ($i=0;$i<3;$i++) {
      $int = $i + 1;
      if( ! $sms->mobio_check($servID,$request->input("code$int"))) {
          return redirect()->to(route('mcCheckoutFailed'))->withErrors(['codeError'=>__('messages.invalidCode',['input'=>$int])]);
      }
}

$cart->success($product->id,$product->server->name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
  $success = true;
  for ($i=0;$i<3;$i++) {
      $int = $i + 1;
      if($success = $success || $sms->mobio_check($servID,$request->input("code$int"))) {
          continue;
          $cart->success($product->id,$product->server->name);
      } else {
          return redirect()->to(route('mcCheckoutFailed'))->withErrors(['codeError'=>__('messages.invalidCode',['input'=>$int])]);
      }
  }
if ($success) $sms->success();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
 $count = 0;
for ($i=0;$i<3;$i++) {
  $int = $i + 1;
  if($sms->mobio_check($servID,$request->input("code$int"))) {
      $count++;
  } else {
      return redirect()->to(route('mcCheckoutFailed'))->withErrors(['codeError'=>__('messages.invalidCode',['input'=>$int])]);
  }
}
if($count == 3) 
$cart->success($product->id,$product->server->name);
```